# Invoice table hold invoices based on their line items

Tags: sql, sum, invoice

I have a table that records the invoices within our company. I need to determine if there is multiple entries for a particular invoice number, and if there is then I need to look at the bin location. I need the results to look like a single invoice entry with all the qty, taxvalue, costvalue and discvalue summed together. The final output should only display a single line for each invoice with all values summed together.

```
Invoice | QtyInvoiced | TaxValue | CostValue | DiscValue | Warehouse | Bin
___________________________________________________________________________
1            1000          5.0        5.0         1.0         KT        23
1             500          5.0        5.0         1.0         KT       Stage
2            1000          3.0        9.0         0.0         KT       Stage
3            1000          5.0        5.0         1.0         KT        19
3             500          5.0        5.0         1.0         KT       Stage
```

Results need to be:

```
Invoice | QtyInvoiced | TaxValue | CostValue | DiscValue | Warehouse | Bin
___________________________________________________________________________
1            1500          10.0        10.0       2.0         KT        
2            1000           3.0         9.0       0.0         KT       
3            1500          10.0        10.0       2.0         KT
```

Comment: interesting. have you tried doing something?

Comment: Is there a user facing application? What's it written in? Do you have any code or database design to show for it? Because you're looking for a specific answer, you must be more specific yourself so we can help you.

Comment: SELECT 
      [Invoice] as Invoice
      ,SUM([QtyInvoiced]) as QtyInvoiced
      ,SUM([Mass]) as Mass
      ,SUM([Volume]) as Volume
      ,SUM([NetSalesValue]) as NetSalesValue
      ,SUM([TaxValue]) as TaxValue
      ,SUM([CostValue]) as CostValue
      ,SUM([DiscValue]) as DiscValue
  FROM dbo.ArTrnDetail  GROUP BY Invoice

Comment: this will work great if I add WHERE Invoice = '123456', but if I run it on the entire table it will still show every invoice entry within the table.

Comment: what's wrong with it showing all your invoices without a `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 0):

This SHOULD get you what you want, you'll probably have to modify it slightly to fit as you didn't really provide a table structure.

```
SELECT invoice_nbr, SUM(qty) As TotalQty,
       SUM(taxvalue) As TotalTaxValue,
       SUM(costvalue) As TotalCostValue,
       SUM(discvalue) As TotalDiscValue
FROM invoices
GROUP BY invoice_nbr
ORDER BY invoice_nbr;
```

Comment: How do you use this example if there are multiple invoices in the invoice table and not all of them have multiple lines on the invoice?

Comment: It should work regardless of if there are multiple invoices with the same number or not. SUM simply sums all the items in the columns for the column(s) the query is grouped on.

Comment: how do I add an image to this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by adding an image to it. You can select other columns but SUM only works for numerics, you cannot perform aggregates on non numeric fields. You would have to write a subquery as part of your initial select list that could concatenate varchar or other typed values together.

Comment: I guess the group by isn't working, I only want to see a single line item for each invoice number.

Comment: Image to show what table looks like and what I need it to look like

Comment: I modified my answer, give that a try. This is just for the totaling of your numeric fields, like I mentioned, for the other fields you will probably want a sub-query as part of your select list in case you need to concatenate things together such as WareHouse in case you have the same invoice number in different warehouses. You might want it to look like 'KT, OH' or something. Same with bin. You might have an order of importance for which one shows up, or you might need to display all of them.